# Adding a Values into a div created from document.createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a DIV that is created from document.createElement,, I have a few text and a image that needs to be added to this DIV. Could some one suggest me the best way to do it? The image path is given in the image variable. Below is the code that i have already written. contentattachpoint is another DIV that is there in the HTML page which is got by

```
var contentattachpoint=document.querySelector('.contentattachPoint');


var year="Year of Manufacture:"+arr[i].year;
var power="Engine Power:"+arr[i].power;
var description="Description:"+arr[i].description;
var image=arr[i].image;
var details = document.createElement("div");
details.setAttribute("id", "details");
details.className = "details";
details.value=year+power+description;
contentattachpoint.appendChild(details)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do what you are already doing use `details.appendChild()`

**Look at this sample example:**

just created a demo example to show you how to dynamically create a div and add paragraph tag and image tag to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/2LAYS/2/

Comment: Yes. this worked. I had to use the property .innerHtml. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

By what I understand of you question I consider that you need text and image both in the div that you created so do something like this

```
details.innerHTML = description + "<img src='"+image+"'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, use the `.append()` function.

Example:

```
$('#details').append('<img src="' + image + '" />');
```

you should also take a look at [Prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

**Source(s)**

[jQuery API - append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
[jQuery API - prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)